# Rails 3.2: When should I use active_scaffold instead of the built-in scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Anyone can tell me what's the difference between https://github.com/activescaffold and the default scaffold in Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Rails scaffold is static, meaning you generate it once, but need to manually update it as your models change.  Active scaffold is dynamically generated, allowing it to change as your application does without the need to manually update your views.